# E(fx)clipce with Inno Setup wrong jre folder name

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, inno-setup, java-8

I am following JavaFX tutorial found at
http://code.makery.ch/java/javafx-8-tutorial-part7/
which describes how to create native installer with 'Inno Setup'.

I am using e(fx)clipse 4.4 with java 8 JRE installed only and 1.8 compiler
and i do it for windows (exe).

Everything works fine, but when i install exported native application it create folders for JRE

```
runtime/jre8/
```

program wont start and says

```
jvm.dll is not found in bundled runtime.
```

if i change manualy `runtime/jre8/` to `runtime/jre/` - it start without any problem.

I did not found any settings in project for specifing runtime path.
How do i make my native installer make right path for runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Just noticed that i was using standalone jre for project `c:\dev\java\jre8` but supposed to use jre from jdk package `c:\dev\java\jdk1.8.0_05\jre`.

Now installer creates proper path for runtime - `runtime/jre/`